# What is going on and how do I fix it?

Tags: google-chrome-os, chroot, xfce

https://prnt.sc/hlt4ey

I'm trying to get onto the xfce4 client from my chromebook (and it has worked before), however now this error is popping up. How do I fix this error?

Comment: Are you logged in as root???  It looks like a permissions error.

Comment: How does one log in as root? Sorry, I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you may not have the right user privileges. According to the error message you provided you are running an Ubuntu Linux environment.

If you haven't tried running the program through the terminal yet, attempt to do so.
The terminal can typically be opened by the key combination `Ctrl+Alt+T` on ubuntu linux.

Try using `sudo` command before running the program. This will run the command you enter using root privileges.

For example, if running the program on your terminal is

```
myName@ubuntu: xfce4
```

And this encounters an error, try to use `sudo` beforehand like so:

```
myName@ubuntu: sudo xfce4
```

Alternatively you can log in and not have to type `sudo` before every command.

```
myName@ubuntu: sudo bash
password:
```

If this fails you may need to update the package that contains the library. This can be done on the terminal in a fashion similar to:

```
myName@ubuntu: sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade xfce4
```